# charts_flutter: Show only the year in horizontal ticks

Tags: flutter, charts

I'm using charts_flutter to generate line charts in Flutter. Given this code:

```
Widget _chart(ctx) => TimeSeriesChart(_data(), domainAxis: ???);

List<Series<Point, DateTime>> _data() =>
    [
        Series<Point, DateTime>(
            id: 'Data',
            colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
            data: store.data,
            domainFn: (Point p, _) => p.timestamp,
            measureFn: (Point p, _) => p.amount,
        )
    ];
```

Produces this chart:

[image: Sample chart]

How do I make the horizontal ticks to only show YEAR?

Comment: What is it currently displaying when running that code? What is `p.timestamp` holding?

Comment: @drogel added screenshot. `p.timestamp` holds a `DateTime` instance, but I only care the year.

Answer (score 1):

If your `domainFn` is being built with `DateTime` objects, you can specify the axis format you desire when building the chart using the `DateTimeAxisSpec` and the `TimeFormatterSpec` classes from the `charts_flutter` package. Check out [this example from the charts_flutter package samples](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/custom_axis_tick_formatters). Here, they are doing something very similar to what you want, i.e., representing some value in the Y axis as a function of some `DateTime` objects in the X axis. As you can see, when building the chart, they use `TimeSeriesChart`, and they set the `domainAxis` parameter to be

```
domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
        tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
            day: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
                format: 'd', transitionFormat: 'MM/dd/yyyy')))
```

In your case, you can just specify a `format` in the `TimeFormatterSpec` constructor, and set its properties so that you show the year instead of the day.

I don't know if you know about it, but the developers from the charts_flutter package have a lot of very useful samples that highlight the different customization options that you can use in your charts in their [sample gallery](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html). They might be useful for you in the future.